# Eliminar palavras repetidas numa string

Tags: c

Dada uma string, preciso verificar quais são as palavras não repetidas (ou as que surgem apenas uma vez) e passar essas mesmas palavras para uma nova string de forma a conseguir guardar essa informação.

Tentei implementar uma função que fizesse isso mas não funcionou, e eu ainda não consegui perceber o que estou a fazer de errado.

```
int i,size=0,j;
char str[]="Eu sou o Pedro. Sou alegre e sou divertido. Tenho um carro e tenho uma casa";
///String esperada = "Eu sou o Pedro alegre e divertido tenho um carro uma casa"
size = strlen(str);
char str_aux[100];
printf("Iniciar\n");
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; i<size; i++ )
    {
        while (str[i]!= ' ')
        {
            if (str[i] != str[j])
            {
                str_aux[i] = str[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("%c",str_aux);
```

Comment: Não entendi porque você está comparando o próximo `char` com o `char` anterior, você não deveria comparar as palavras?

Comment: mas comparar char com char não vai definir se a palavra é igual, você deveria fazer um vetor de caracteres, estou testando minha lógica aqui e se eu conseguir eu respondo já já

Comment: Na linguagem C, é sim possível fazer a comparação de 'strings' (Vetor de caracteres)... Para efetuá-la, utiliza-se a função strcmp... Será necessário incluir (#include <string.h>)
Exemplo: if(strcmp(checkpass, pass) == 0)
ou seja compara se o vetor de caracteres checkpass é igual ao vetor de caracteres pass.

Comment: Você tentou usar uma tabela de hash?

Comment: João, a resposta dada solucionou o seu problema? Você precisa que alguma coisa nela seja modificada ou de mais alguma explicação? Se a resposta é suficiente, você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **✓** no lado esquerdo da publicação, isso ajuda a mostrar aos outros usuários que a resposta está certa e que eles podem usar esta solução caso tenham o mesmo problema que você.

Comment: @João Tem algum problema com a resposta? Vi que você marcou e desmarcou o aceite.

Comment: Pronto, @João, encontrei essa outra função aqui: http://www.facom.ufu.br/~madriana/PP/TP6.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Seu código está muito simples para a função dele, você está errando pois está comparando caracteres e não strings, um `char` não significa uma string, mas mesmo que significasse o código ainda faltaria algo, você está comparando apenas com o caractere anterior, você precisaria comparar com todas as outras palavras.

A lógica que eu segui para esse algoritmo foi: Declarei uma `struct` com um vetor de `char` dentro, e, logo após, declarei um `vetor` dessa `struct` (basicamente um `vetor` de strings do tamanho da quantidade de palavras na frase), em cada "string" devo colocar uma palavra da frase, mas antes verifico se há alguma igual, se não houver eu adiciono, por fim eu só imprimo o vetor inteiro que vai ter toda a frase com nenhuma palavra repetida. O código abaixo (Precisa ter um certo conhecimento sobre funções, vetores e ponteiros):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{ //essa struct servirá para cada palavra
    char letras[15];
}String;

int qtd_palavra(char *frase){
    int i, qtd_char, qtd_palavra = 1; //inicializo com 1 pois antes do primeiro espaço já há uma palavra

    qtd_char=strlen(frase);
    for(i=0; i<qtd_char; i++){
        if((frase[i] != '\0') && (frase[i]==' '))
            qtd_palavra++;
    }

    return qtd_palavra;
}
void main(){
    int i=0, j=0, palavras_ok=0, qtd_char; 
    int str_igual=0; //booleano para definir se a palavra é diferente de todos, 1 para verdadeiro e 0 para falso
    String palavra; //usada como "cache" para verificar se há alguma palavra igual
    char str[]="Eu sou o Pedro. Sou alegre e sou divertido. Tenho um carro e tenho uma casa";
    String palavras[qtd_palavra(str)];//defino um vetor de "strings" do tamanho da quantidade de palavras na frase

    qtd_char=strlen(str);

    for(i=0; i<=qtd_char; i++){
        if(str[i]==' '||str[i]=='\0'){ //se for o fim da palavra, no caso, se for espaço, ou fim da frase
            str_igual=0; //deixo a variavel igual a falso sempre no começo do loop
            palavra.letras[j++]=' '; //da um espaço no final da palavra
            palavra.letras[j]='\0'; //finaliza a palavra

            j=0;
            while(j<palavras_ok){
                if (strcasecmp(palavra.letras,palavras[j].letras)==0){ //se a palavra pegada for igual alguma já preenchida
                    str_igual=1; //defino como verdadeiro, caso tenha alguma palavra igual
                    break; //finaliza o ciclo pois já há uma palavra igual
                }
                j++;
            }
            if(str_igual==0){ //se não tiver nenhuma palavra igual
                strcpy(palavras[palavras_ok++].letras,palavra.letras); //copia a palavra para uma nova palavra e adiciona mais um ao numero de palavras
            }
            strcpy(palavra.letras,""); //defino a palavra que sempre uso como vazia novamente
            j=0;
        }else{
            palavra.letras[j++]=str[i];
        }
    }

    j=0;
    while(j<palavras_ok){
        printf("%s",palavras[j++].letras);
    }

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}
```

Mas pra o código "Eu" é diferente de "eu", já que o strcmp é "case sensitive", acho que deve ter outra função pra comparar com maiuscula e minuscula, se eu achar eu adiciono aqui.

Modifiquei de `strcmp()` para `strcasecmp()` que é a função case-insensitve de `strcmp()`.